# using methods and I cant get it to read two different inputs

Tags: java, methods

I am currently trying to create a bmi calculator and i am stuck with trying to get the feet and inches of a persons height into one value in inches as i do not know how to catch the two different values (feet and inches) and then verify them.

public class BMI {

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Value between 2 and 7: " + heightInInches(2,7));
    System.out.println("Value between 0 and 11: " + heightInInches(0,11));

    System.out.println("Value between 3 and 30: " + weightInPounds(3,30));
    System.out.println("Value between 0 and 13: " + weightInPounds(0,13));
}

public static int heightInInches(int lower, int upper)
{
    Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Enter your height between %d and %d: ", lower, upper);
    int height = kybd.nextInt();

    while (height < lower || height > upper)
    {
        System.out.printf("Retry between %d and %d:" , lower, upper);
        height = kybd.nextInt();
    }     

    return height;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a simple BMI calculator, you could play around by amending your own conditions.

```
static int heightInInches( int f,int i){
            int in=f*12;
            int inches=i+in;
            return inches;
        }
        static int weightInPounds(int stone, int p){
            int po=stone*14;
            int pounds=p+po;
            return pounds;
        }
        static int calculateBMI(int height,int weight ){
            int w=weight*703;
            int h=height*height;
            int bmi = w/h;
            return bmi;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args){
            Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter height in feet (2-7): ");
            int feet=input.nextInt();
            while( !(feet>= 2 && feet<=7))
            {
                System.out.println("Retry between 2 and 7 :");
                feet=input.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("Enter height in inch(0-11): ");
            int inch=input.nextInt();
            while( !(inch>= 0 && inch<=11))
            {
                System.out.println("Retry between 0 and 11 :");
                inch=input.nextInt();
            }
            System.out.print("Enter weight in stone: ");
            int stone=input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter weight in pound: ");
            int pound=input.nextInt();
            int height=heightInInches(feet,inch);
            int weight=weightInPounds(stone,pound);
            int bmi=calculateBMI(height,weight);
            System.out.println("BMI is: "+bmi);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't looks right `while (height < inches || height > inches)`

Infact, the entire `heightInInches()` has to be modified. Your way of accepting input from user by displaying feet and inches is incorrect.

Comment: i know that bit is wrong cause i need to verify the height but doing that i cant have seperate feet or inches ???

Comment: What do you mean can't have separate feet or inches? Firstly you do not have a clear lower or upper bound for feet or inches ... ask the user to input a value between what?

Comment: ive just corrected that as i been playing around and put it back to how it was

Comment: If you wish to ask the user to enter his height between 5 feet and 5 feet 10 inches, you would either need to specify it correctly or at the least do basic conversions in your code.

Comment: yeah but they both got to be in one input so the values can b verified else if i have two loops it just repeats even if it gets verified

Comment: Both as in feet and inches? If you get input in inches, you can go ahead with your BMI calc right? Why do u need feet? Even if u did need it, just write a simple calc to convert inches to feet (divide by 12 and append the remainder - 64 implies 64/12 - 5"4)

Comment: but the spec says it has to be in feet and inches and then the prorgam converts them for the user ???

Comment: If the spec says that they probably mean accepting something like 5"4 and converting it to 5*12+4=64 and then comparing if it is within the range. If yes, go ahead and complete your BMI calc

Comment: but then why they specify the verification ranges and have them seperate?? i think they are trying to be difficult :(

Comment: Verification ranges are not being accepted by the user right? Your program defines that. So all you have to do is compare if 64 (which u calc from 5"4) is between 40 and 70

Comment: well there controlling what they can enter hence i need to some how get the feet and inches from there input and then can convert them

Comment: Do you mean you want to know how to accept something like 5"4 from the user? Or do you mean user can enter either feet or inches or both? Can you plz be more clear?

Comment: they enter the feet first then that gets verified and then they enter the inches but it uses the same input line and variable

Answer (score 0):

if you want to keep your code, which i wouldnt recommend. keep the scanner inside the while loop like this

```
while(yourcond){
   kybd = new Scanner(System.in);//take the input again
     height = kybd.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May you want to query the user for feet, store it in a member variable, then query for the inches and do your computations. Example:

Modified main Class:

```
    package feetinch;

    public class FeetInch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HeightQuery heightQuery = new HeightQuery();

        heightQuery.queryForFeet();
        heightQuery.queryForInches();

        System.out.println("Result=" + heightQuery.getHeight());


    }
}
```

New Class:

```
    package feetinch;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class HeightQuery {
    private int feet, inches;

    public void queryForFeet() {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Enter your height in feet: ");
        feet = kybd.nextInt();
    }

    public void queryForInches() {
        Scanner kybd = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.printf("Enter your height in inches: ");
        inches = kybd.nextInt();
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return (feet * 12 )  + inches;
    }

}
```